# 'slackr' R package not recognizing Github env variables

Tags: r, github, yaml, slack, slackr

I am trying to automate my slackr posts through Github Actions and I have a question:

Was trying to run an [R script that included slackr](https://github.com/invisibae/slack_bot/blob/main/some_tests.R) through a [github aciton](https://github.com/invisibae/slack_bot/runs/6256910652?check_suite_focus=true) and I keep running into a problem where my script runs without any errors but fails to post to slack because while the requisite environment variables ('SLACK_CHANNEL', 'SLACK_TOKEN', 'SLACK_USERNAME', etc.) are present in the action environment, they're all unfortunately blank.

It was my understanding that I could set up environment variables ahead of time through [Actions Secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets), call the env and specify the variables [in my yaml script](https://github.com/invisibae/slack_bot/actions/runs/2257803851/workflow), and simply use slackr() along with Sys.getenv() to point the script to my env variables rather than using slackr_setup and exposing my API key.

While I'm encouraged by the fact that R seems to be seeing the env variables I set up through Action secrets, I am still unsure about why R thinks they are blank.  Could it be that I am declaring the environment at the wrong point in the yaml file?  Is R simply incompatible with Actions Secrets?  Something else?

[empty env variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb7lb.png)

Comment: This probably has to do with the permissons in effect.  Can you echo any secret and see it listed?  (This page https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/GitHub-Actions-Secrets-Example-Token-Tutorial gives a trick that shows how to get them to echo.  Don't do this with real secrets, because everyone will see them.)

Comment: BTW, the list you linked to as "empty env variables" wasn't what R saw, that was Github hiding the values.  To see what R sees, change your R script to print the env variable.

Comment: Apologies, [here's an example of a try where I had R print all of its env variables](https://github.com/invisibae/slack_bot/runs/6195737385?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: Okay, I think the issue is that you echoed the secrets into `.Renviron`.  Github will echo blanks into that file, and it will override the environment variables.  So if you just skip that step, things should be visible in R.

Comment: This was my thought too at the time but my concern is 1) shouldn't the print env variables job print them as ***** rather than blanks? and 2) it's my fault for not sharing [but there's versions of this where I don't make the .Renviron file and output all env variables in R and the values are still hidden](https://github.com/invisibae/slack_bot/runs/6257878784?check_suite_focus=true)

Comment: Did you try printing them using the suggestion in my first comment?  Maybe they really are blank, because of some other issue.